# Cordova app: Unexpected Identifier in Index.js

Tags: javascript, cordova

Here's the function where it says the problem

```
saveData: function() {
$.ajax({
    //If you are using the google option, the type should be 'get'
    //If you are using the server option, the type should be 'post'
    type: 'post',
    url: '80.241.217.250',
    data: localStore,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(result) {
        var pid = localStore.participant_id,
            snoozed = localStore.snoozed,
            uniqueKey = localStore.uniqueKey;
        localStore.clear();
        localStore.participant_id = pid;
        localStore.snoozed = snoozed;
        localStore.uniqueKey = uniqueKey;
    },
    error: function(request, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
}
```

The code is from [this](https://github.com/sabrinathai/ExperienceSampler/blob/master/ExperienceSampler%20Template%20Files/ExperienceSampler%20Template%20files%20for%20Android/js/index.js) file on github. I'm following the tutorial from ExperienceSampler.com. When I run it, I get the error `Syntax Error: Unexpcted Identifier` Any idea why?

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmT5N.png)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier   index.js:601
```

And that line is the function above

Comment: could you please share the stack error?

Comment: I've added an image of the error. Thank you for replying :)

Comment: It says line 601 because I added some lines above. The equivalent line on the github page would be line 593

Comment: What about if you comment that function? it works?

Comment: also, do you have jquery loaded?

Comment: > What about if you comment that function? it works? < No it doesn't. I get the same error for another function and I don't know how to load jquery. Can you help me out there?

Comment: check it out -> https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: Added it. Still getting the error. Also sorry for the late reply